# Erro setar valor dos Parâmetros na Query

Tags: lazarus, zeos

Tenho um problema nessa *SQL* no *Lazarus* com *Zeos* e *Firebird*
toda vez que executo a `procedure` da o erro.
Eu já Adicionei os Parâmetros no componente `TZQuery`.

- Mensagem de Erro:

  > ```
  > [Notificação Exceções Depurador]
  > Projeto Autosad elevou classe exceção 'EZSQLException' com a mensagem:
  > SQL Error:  Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code =
  > -303 arithmetic exception,numeric overflow, or string truncation string right truncation
  > Error Code: -303. <br> Incompatible column/host variable data type The SQL:
  > Select T1.DATA_AUDIENCIA, T1.HORA_AUDIENCIA, T2.NUMERO_PROCESSO, T1.NUMERO_E_VARA,
  > T1.ORGAO, T1.COMARCA, T1.ADVOGADO_DILIGENTE, T3.NOME_CLIENTE, T2.PARTE_CONTRARIA
  > from AUDIENCIAS T1, PROCESSOS T2, CLIENTES T3
  > where T1.NUMERO_PROCESSO = T2.NUMERO_PROCESSO and T2.COD_CLIENTE = T3.COD_CLIENTE and
  > T1.DATA_AUDIENCIA >= ? and T1.HORA_AUDIENCIA >= ?
  > order by T1.DATA_AUDIENCIA, T1.HORA_AUDIENCIA; 
  >
  > No arquivo:
  > 'C:\Lazarus\components\Zeosdbo\src\dbc\ZDbcInterbase6Utils.pas' na linha 910
  > ```
- Código:

  ```
  procedure TfrmEntradaSistema.AlimentaQryAudienciasInicial;
  var vSql:String;
  begin
    // Prepara e executa QUERY com as PROXIMAS AUDIENCIAS para a Tela Inicial
    vSql := 'Select '+
        '  T1.DATA_AUDIENCIA, '+
        '  T1.HORA_AUDIENCIA, '+
        '  T2.NUMERO_PROCESSO, '+
        '  T1.NUMERO_E_VARA, '+
        '  T1.ORGAO, '+
        '  T1.COMARCA, '+
        '  T1.ADVOGADO_DILIGENTE, '+
        '  T3.NOME_CLIENTE, '+
        '  T2.PARTE_CONTRARIA '+
        'from '+
        '  AUDIENCIAS T1, '+
        '  PROCESSOS T2, '+
        '  CLIENTES T3 '+
        'where '+
        '  T1.NUMERO_PROCESSO = T2.NUMERO_PROCESSO and '+
        '  T2.COD_CLIENTE     =  T3.COD_CLIENTE    and '+
        '  T1.DATA_AUDIENCIA >= :AudData and '+
        '  T1.HORA_AUDIENCIA >= :AudHora '+
        'order by T1.DATA_AUDIENCIA, T1.HORA_AUDIENCIA';
    DataModuleGeral2.qryAudienciasInicial.Close;
    DataModuleGeral2.qryAudienciasInicial.SQL.Clear;
    DataModuleGeral2.qryAudienciasInicial.SQL.Add(vSql);
    // Parâmetro
    DataModuleGeral2.qryAudienciasInicial.Params.ParamValues['AudData'] := QuotedStr(StringReplace(DateToStr(DataModuleGeral.tbParametrosDATA_SISTEMA.AsDateTime),'/','.',[rfReplaceAll]));
    DataModuleGeral2.qryAudienciasInicial.Params.ParamValues['AudHora'] := QuotedStr(TimeToStr(Time));
    DataModuleGeral2.qryAudienciasInicial.ExecSQL;
    DataModuleGeral2.qryAudienciasInicial.Active := True;
    DataModuleGeral2.qryAudienciasInicial.First;
  end;
  ```

Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Provavelmente esse erro deve estar relacionado a conversão de datas.

Comment: e como é que resolve?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Parâmetro
DataModuleGeral2.qryAudienciasInicial.Params.ParamByName['AudData'].AsString :=
```

Não testei seu código. Mas isso foi a primeira coisa que me chamou a atenção.

Comment: Não entendi sua resposta?